# Nlog Azure Storage blob name does not accept layout variables

Tags: azure, blob, storage, nlog, blobstorage

**Nlog Azure Storage blob name does not accept layout variables**

When nLog logging writing to the Azure blob, the storageBlobName target variable does not appear to accept any of the standard NLog variables that can be used to generate dynamic/custom blob names.

I have define below configuration in app.Config file.

```
<nlog .............>
<variable name="ABC" value="XYZ" />
<targets>  
<target xsi:type="AzureBlobStorageLogger"
         name="Trace-BlobStorageLogger" 
                       storageConnectionString="......." 
                       storageContainerName="AzureBlobContainerName" 
                       storageBlobName="nlog-{var:ABC}-azure-storage-trace.txt" /> </targets> 
    <rules>  </rules> 
    </nlog>
```

Comment: Have you tried: https://github.com/JDetmar/NLog.Extensions.AzureStorage

Comment: Yes, but layout is also not working

Comment: I think you need both changes, the other package (comment of Rolf) + the fix in config (from Ivan)

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed a $ before {}, you can take a look at this [article](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file#variables):

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have also tried with this but still, it is not working. But when i use xsi:type="File" then its working fine.

Comment: @AmitMaru, you can post an answer for your findings, and it would be helpful for others who have the same issue.